# How can i post a model to the controller from the view?

Tags: html, .net, forms, razor, model-view-controller

I have currently been sending a textarea and a list of items to the view through the body of the http. However i have now been attempting to move towards a more elegant solution and want to send it as a model. I have looked online and i can't seem to find anything that helps me understand.

I know that you can either post data in html using the "html.beginForm" and just using the "form" tag. i use the form tag to send my items. How can i add a model to this tag so that the data sent via post has the desired format

```
<form name="message" id="message" action="/message/" method="post">
<ul id="list">
    <li style="list-style-type:disc;">E-mail: <input type="email" name="emailaddress" required></li>
</ul>

<p><button type="button" onclick="addEmailField()">Add email</button></p>
<script>
    function addEmailField() {
        var ul = document.getElementById("message").getElementsByTagName("UL")[0];
        if (ul.childElementCount < 25) {
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.innerHTML = "<li>E-mail: <input type='email' name='emailaddress' required></li>";
            ul.appendChild(li);
        } else {
            alert("Reached limit of 25 emails, can not add more");
        }
    }
</script>

<p><button type="button" onclick="removeEmailField()">Remove email</button></p>
<script>
    function removeEmailField() {
        var ul = document.getElementById("message").getElementsByTagName("UL")[0];
        if (ul.childElementCount > 1) {
            ul.removeChild(ul.lastChild);
        }
    }
</script><br><br><br>

<h3>Message</h3>
<textarea name="textarea" style="width:750px;height:300px;resize:none;" maxlength="3500" ; required></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

my model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace OneTimeTool.Models
{
    public class ClientInput
    {
        public string[] Emails { get; set; }

        public string Message { get; set; }

    }
}
```

i want to be able to use a object in the controller to access the values (thye list of emails and the textarea) instead of manually extracting them from the body.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult message(ClientInput model)
```

Comment: You can use AJAX call and pass your model in data attribute

Answer (score 0):

Much like @Dilip said, you can use an ajax call to pass the data as a string to the controller.

Add an id to your textarea such as `_message`

```
var textareaMessage = $("#_message").val();.

var json = '{textarea: "' + textareaMessage  + '"}'; 

$.ajax({
    url:'@Url.Action("//Action", "//Controller")',
    type:'POST',
    data: json,
    contentType:'Application/json',
    success:function(result){
        //Do whatever
    }
})
```